# How to add active class on conditions?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel

I am doing a project in **Laravel**. In blade file, I have rating options for the image. When I click on next button then without page reload I am displaying image with ratings and same for the previous button.A User can change the rating on **`click`** which is also done ***using ajax call***. Now my problem is I want to add an active class to a rated button and whenever I do next prev actions, it should handle the active class thing. I am really unable to resolve this issue.

```
<ul class="btnforimages">
    <li>
        <strong>Rate this photo:</strong>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="imgstep" id="rate_1" ng-click="">1 - poor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="imgstep" id="rate_2" ng-click="">2 - needs work</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="imgstep" id="rate_3" ng-click="">3 - not bad</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="imgstep" id="rate_4" ng-click="">4 - small tweaks</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="imgstep" id="rate_5" ng-click="">5 - perfect</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please let know how to handle this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will remove the active class from all siblings and add active class for the selected `li` if it doesn't have an active class.

```
$('.btnforimages li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active"))
       $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**Note:** If you want to remove the active class from the selected element on second click use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` and remove the check for active class.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply... but It should gets changed when I go to next image as well as when user change rating as well

Comment: @Amarja Updated my answer. But what should happen if you click on the same image once again? Should we remove active class or should be retain the active class??